# Cefsharp, can't join a Teams video meeting

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

For a software project we need to offer Teams video meetings in a Cef form. My idea is to use CefSharp for this.

Unfortunately a Teams video meeting won't start in the CefSharp WinForms Minimal Example (has enable-media-stream on by default, but if I turn it off I get the same error). Teams video meeting does work in e.g. a Chrome browser. I looked at the DevTools console but I can't make anything of the console info you'll get. Does anyone how to make this work?

How to reproduce:

1. Start the latest CefSharp Winforms MinimalExample (you can disable enable-media-stream if you want to rule this out, same result)
2. In MinimalExample browse to https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_YWQ1ZTlkZWQtNmFjZS00NjNlLWEzZDctMjYwMzJkMjBkZWJj%40thread.v2/0?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%226cc7185e-802a-416b-9249-9409da9cd7aa%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%226b7977a8-9017-443c-a812-b366db0f759f%22%7d
3. Click Join on the web instead
4. Click Join now
5. You get a mesage: 'Sorry, we couldn't connect you.'

If you do the same in Chrome you can enter the meeting without any problem.

Comment: Try downloading the CEF Sample application from http://opensource.spotify.com/cefbuilds/index.html test using that, if  I had to guess the video/audio codecs required aren't supported. Only free audio and video codecs are supported. If it works in the CEF Sample application then it can be made to work in CefSharp.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just checked with the CEF Sample Client it works. It does not have enable-media-stream enabled but you can join the meeting. If I disable enable-media-stream in the CefSharp sample client I still get the same error.

Comment: In the CEF Sample Client you can see the video and hear the audio of the other participants so codecs are probably fine.

Comment: I now also tried the WPF Minimal Example. This one also works directly. However I really like to use it in a existing WinForms project.

Comment: You can open `chrome://version/` in the `WinForms` and `WPF` version to compare the command line args used. This is typically the difference between the two.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3113#issuecomment-620855847

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Winforms version of CefSharp has does not have the flag disable-gpu-compositing, which e.g. the WPF version has. Also this behaviour seems to be fixed in Cef version 81. Thanks Amaitland for helping out!